# Нужно ли ограничивать права на папку, куда заливаются фотографии, которые проверяются на допустимые расширения?

Tags: веб-программирование, безопасность

У меня на сайте есть возможность заливать фотографии. В скрипте с сохранением фотографий проверяется их расширение - последние символы в названии файла после последней точки. Если расширение не входит в список допустимых (например, png, jpg, jpeg, bmp, gif), то файл не проходит валидацию.

Вопрос. Нужно ли ограничивать права на папку, куда заливаются фотографии? Я слышал, что для любых папок, куда можно залить файлы, нужно запретить выполнение (chmod). Либо можно еще вот так:

```
<FilesMatch "\.([Pp][Hh][Pp]|[Cc][Gg][Ii]|[Pp][Ll]|[Ph][Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll])\.?.*">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

И если нужно, то зачем это делать? Ведь и так в папку не могут попасть плохие файлы.

Comment: Стоит на уровне web-сервера (.htaccess) запретить выполнение скриптов из любых папок, которые доступны для записи самим выполняемым скриптам. А заливаются туда при работе файлы именно пользователем или даже скрипты просто пишут свои логи, это не имеет значения. Настройки прав выполнения должны защищать от любых ошибок в приложении, позволяющих записать что то выполняемое

Comment: @Mike, а того кода, который я привел, хватит? я про FilesMatch.

Comment: Он запрещает просто доступ к файлам с конкретным расширением. А стоит запрещать выполнение как таковое. т.е. `Options -ExecCGI` и `php_flag engine off`  (для apache) (глобальный конфиг сервера должен разрешать применение этих опций в .htaccess). ну и сами файлы .htaccess не должны быть доступны для записи. А еще лучше вообще в конфигах веб-сервера (а не .htaceess) разрешать выполнение только в тех папках где у вас действительно есть скрипты

Comment: @Mike
"(глобальный конфиг сервера должен разрешать применение этих опций в .htaccess)." а как разрешить применять? что поменять в глобальном конфиге?